# Pair Android wear with a wireless scanner

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os, moto-360

We have already deployed a [phone + scanner] based app for our client but, now we are thinking of deploying a [wear + scanner] solution. However, we are not sure whether the wear app can function independently of the phone.

To put it simply, we want to connect our bluetooth scanner [Motorola RS507](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/IN-EN/Mobile+Networks+RFID+and+BarCode+Scanners/Mobile+Computers/Wearable+Computers/RS507_US-EN) to watch and then use the on-site wifi to connect to internet. Can the pairing be done easily? Can wear operate in this use case ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259692/does-android-wear-support-directly-access-the-internet

Comment: Thanks, as far as I understood, that post focuses more on reliable data transfer b/w phone+wear over bluetooth/wifi. We however, intend to use wear (+ scanner) independently. Also, one comment said : "2. Stick to Data Layer API , you cannot send http request directly from watch. Fetch internet data from the phone, then transfer it to watch with Data Layer API.". Is that written in stone ?

Comment: did you ever figure it out, I'm trying to do the exact same thing for my company. so far I'm hitting a dead end on this.

Comment: Nope, we figured we need to buy 'newer' scanner...so, project put on hold now.If you ever figure it out please do post the answer.